# What is the PDF of $Y = |X|$ given $X\sim \mathcal{N} (0,\sigma ^2)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

I've faced this question and found a solution for it, so I decided to share it with others; maybe it'll help them. Also, the question solves somehow the generality of it.

Question: Given $X\sim \mathcal{N} (0,\sigma ^2)$ and $Y = |X|$, find the PDF of $Y$.

Comment: If you have a correct answer to your own question, you should post it as such down here

Comment: Folded normal: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

A way to solve such a problem, in general, is to use the CDF of the random variables since it's easier to use it in continuous random variables.

For the question above here is the solution:

$P(Y\leq y)=P(|X|\leq y)=P(-y\leq X\leq y)=F_x(y)-F_x(-y)$.

Notice that we moved between equations according to basic probability laws so there's nothing complicated. Now in order to find the PDF we need to derive the last formula.

$\frac{d}{dy}F_x(y)-\frac{d}{dy}F_x(-y)=f_x(y)-(-1\cdot f_x(-y))=f_x(y)+f_x(-y)=f_x(y)+f_x(y)=2\cdot f_x(y)$

Notice that the $f_x(-y)=f_x(y)$ is not a trivial move, it happened just because $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma ^2)$ so if you check $f_x(y) \ and\ f_x(-y)$ you get the same result and therefore it's true.

To the end we get the equation:

$f_Y(y)=$
$\left\{ 
  \begin{array}{ c l }
    0 & \quad  \textrm{otherwise} \\
    2\cdot f_X(x)                 & \quad y \geq 0
  \end{array}
\right.$